# creating theorem-like environments within 'notes' (see example)

Tags: environments, indentation, theorems, ntheorem

I would like to create the following style to write mathematics:

[image: designpage]

In fact the above I created myself but some numbers and spacing I had to set manually (and I would like this to be automatic of course).

So the following are important to me:

- I want the page to consists of 'notes' that are numbered like 1.1, 1.2 etc., where the first number refers to the section/paragraph (so in my example there are four notes in section 1). With every note I want to have the possibility to add a title that appears boldface (for example note 1.1).
- Within a note I want to have the possibility to add a theorem-like environment (in my example you can find 'remark', 'lemma' etc.). Preferably I would like to have one single command for this, and then the possibility to name it the way I want (so lemma or proposition or maybe something else). Also I want them to be numbered within the note they occur (see example), unless I choose them to be non-numbered (so in my example the 'remark' is not numbered).
- Between these theorem-like environments I want to include some small space (I chose \medskip in the example). But I don't want this space to get doubled whenever I have two of these environments one after the other.
- Last but not least: I want the title of a section, the first word of a note, and the heading of the theorem-like environments to be aligned (say one paragraph indent).

Any help or advice is appreciated. Of course, partial solutions are also welcome and I can provide details in case something is not clear.

Thanks a lot in advance! AYK

Comment: You're requesting a lot of things, but provide nothing ;-) The `amsthm` package shows how to make theorems, as well as `ntheorem`

Comment: Because I don't know how to fix the numbering within the notes. This is my main problem so you can forget about the rest if I asked too much.

Comment: Is there any reason why ‘Proposition’  and ‘Remark’  use an em-dash as  a separator with the following text, while ‘ Definition’ and ‘Lemma’ don't?

Comment: All of them (should) use em-dash, I don't see a difference between the ones you mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be an approximation to your wish; however, I find the numbering scheme too fussy: I see no reason for statements to be numbered under notes.

If `\newnote` is immediately followed by `\begin`, a theorem-like statement is assumed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifnotebegin
\newcounter{note}[section]
\renewcommand{\thenote}{\thesection.\arabic{note}}
\newcommand{\newnote}{\@ifnextchar\begin\xnew@note\new@note}
\newcommand{\new@note}[1][]{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}%
  \refstepcounter{note}%
  \global\notebeginfalse
  \noindent\formatnote{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\formatnote}[1]{%
  \makebox[\parindent][l]{\normalfont\bfseries\thenote}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\textbf{#1}\ \fi
}
\newcommand{\xnew@note}{%
  \refstepcounter{note}%
  \global\notebegintrue
}
\newcommand\notenumberorindent{%
  \ifnotebegin
    \formatnote{}%
  \else
    \hspace*{\parindent}%
  \fi
  \global\notebeginfalse
}
\makeatother

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\normalfont\itshape,
  notefont=\normalfont\itshape,
  bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
  notebraces={\textnormal{(}}{\textnormal{)}},
  headformat=\notenumberorindent\NAME\ \textup{({\bfseries\NUMBER})}\NOTE,
  headpunct=\ ---,
]{ayk}

\declaretheorem[
  style=ayk,
  within=note,
  name=Lemma,
]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[
  style=ayk,
  sibling=lemma,
  name=Proposition,
]{proposition}

\counterwithin{equation}{lemma}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{2em}}

\begin{document}

\section{First notes}

\newnote[Hello]
\lipsum[2]

\begin{lemma}[Some Lemma]
A lemma about something
A lemma about something
A lemma about something
A lemma about something
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
Some other lemma Bla bla
\end{lemma}

\begin{proposition}
Some Proposition
\begin{equation}
  E = mc^2 
\end{equation}
\end{proposition}

\newnote
This note has no title. \lipsum[2]

\begin{lemma}[Some Lemma]
A lemma about something
A lemma about something
A lemma about something
A lemma about something
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
Some other lemma Bla bla
\end{lemma}

\begin{proposition}
Some Proposition
\begin{equation}
  E = mc^2 
\end{equation}
\end{proposition}

\newnote\begin{lemma}[Some Lemma]
A lemma about something
A lemma about something
A lemma about something
A lemma about something
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
Some other lemma Bla bla
\end{lemma}

\begin{proposition}
Some Proposition
\begin{equation}
  E = mc^2 
\end{equation}
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is an offense to my eyes ;-)

Comment: This has been amazingly useful, wow! 

I would like to ask you the following:
- Is it possible to make also 'unnumbered versions' of the theorem-like environments? For example, is it possible that I have a the usual commands and a 'starred version' to get the same environment without numbering (since I would like to chose which environments get numbered).
- How to make the section heading also start exactly after 1 paragraph indent?
- How can I change the spacing between the notes to my own taste?

Again, thanks a lot! I am learning new stuff by examing your code.

Comment: @AYK With `thmtools` it's quite easy; add the option `numbered=no` to `\declaretheorem`. For the spacing, change `\topsep` to `\baselineskip`. Sorry, but I won't change my answer for aspects that are completely out of the question, like section titles.

Comment: Ok I will create unnumbered declaretheorems. And what about the spacing between the 'notes'? Since I am a tex-noob I am not able to find the exact parameters in your code.

Comment: @AYK Change `\addvspace{\topsep}` to `\addvspace{\baselineskip}`

Comment: Ok thanks, in fact I tried this but it didn't work for all the notes. The ones that begin directly with a theorem-like environment don't get separated.

Answer (score 2):

Only preliminary solution... indentation not done yet.

`\newtheorem{foo}{Foo}[section]` will define an environment named `foo`, titled `Foo` and a counter named (you guess it -- `foo` ;-)), which is reset each time the `section` counter is stepped.

`\newtheorem{otherfoo}[foo]{Otherfoo}` will define an environment named `otherfoo`, titled `Otherfoo` and **no** counter -- it will use the counter `foo` instead, i.e. `foo` and `otherfoo` share the counters.

Since the counter formats should be changed, this has to be done manually, `counterwithin` from `chngcntr` is no help, here, in my point of view.

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{amsthm}

%\usepackage{xpatch}

\newtheorem{notes}{Note}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{\normalfont\textit{Lemma}}[notes]
\newtheorem{proposition}[lemma]{\normalfont\textit{Proposition}}

\renewcommand{\thelemma}{(\thenotes.\arabic{lemma})}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thenotes.\arabic{lemma}.\arabic{equation}}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\section{First notes}

\begin{notes}{Hello}
\blindtext
\begin{lemma}{Some Lemma}
\blindtext
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}{Some other lemma}
Bla bla
\end{lemma}

\begin{proposition}{Some Proposition}
\begin{equation}
  E = mc^2 
\end{equation}
\end{proposition}

\begin{proposition}{Some Proposition}
\begin{equation}
  E^2 = (mc^2)^2 +\left(pc\right)^2
\end{equation}

\end{proposition}

\end{notes}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll update later on

Answer (score 2):

A solution based on `ntheorem`, `mathtools` and `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{1.1cm}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\newtagform{bold}{\bfseries(}{)}
\usetagform{bold}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\bfseries}{\rlap{§\thesection.}}{1.1cm}{\lsstyle\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\rlap{\thesubsection.}}{1.1cm}{\mbox{}}
\usepackage[thref, amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem}%
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{myplain}%
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ \textup{\bfseries(##2)}\ \theorem@separator]}%
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ \textup{\bfseries(##2)}\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{myplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{\textemdash}
\newtheorem{lemma}{\hspace*{1.1cm}Lemma}[subsection]%
\newtheorem{prop}[lemma]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{defn}[lemma]{Definition}

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremseparator{ \textemdash}
\newtheorem{remark}{\hspace*{1.1cm}Remark}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\diamondsuit}}
\newtheorem{proof}{\hspace*{1.1cm}Proof}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newcommand\note[1][]{\subsection{#1}\ifblank{#1}{\hskip-\labelsep}{\relax}}% 

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{equation}{lemma}

\begin{document}

\section{Some section}
\note[Some optional title]
\lipsum[1]

\note[]
\lipsum[3]

\begin{remark}
\lipsum[5]
\end{remark}

\note
\lipsum[4]
\begin{lemma}\label{lemma1}\lipsum[3]
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
A brilliant proof. Blah blah blah. A brilliant proof. Blah blah blah. A brilliant proof. Blah blah blah. A brilliant proof with an unlikely final formula
 \[n! \sim_\infty \sqrt{2\pi n}\Bigl(\frac{n}{\mathrm e}\Bigr)^n.\] %
\end{proof}
\lipsum[5]
\begin{prop}A very interesting proposition, with an amazing formula:
\begin{equation}\label{quadratic}
  x_0 ,x_1 =\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{equation}
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]